# Converting string to date 12/29/2014 00:00:00.000

Tags: c#

I am not able to convert a string of following format "12/29/2014 00:00:00.000"
to a datetime value....I tried using following code.

Can someone help me please.

```
var value = "12/29/2014 00:00:00.000";
DateTime validDate = new DateTime();

DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", null,System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None,out validDate);                    
DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out validDate);
DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "MM/dd/yyyy", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out validDate);

Console.WriteLine(validDate);
```

Comment: irc milliseconds are `fff`, not `SSS`.

Comment: @Filburt, add a answer and I'll vote for you.

Comment: @Richard - I tried DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.FFF", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out validDate) - dint work.

Comment: In what way is it not working? (Please include *in the question* not a comment.)

Comment: It works fine for me with FFF...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
using System;

public class Program
 {
public static void Main()
{
    var date = "12/29/2014 00:00:00.000";

    IFormatProvider culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US", true);
    DateTime checkindate = Convert.ToDateTime(date, culture);
   Console.WriteLine(checkindate);
  }
}
```

use CultureInfo

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try this one

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("12/29/2014 00:00:00.000", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: {"The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar."} - I got this error

Comment: @Relativity: With the *exact* string value you've given here?

Comment: it should work try by double check given format string `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff`

Answer (score 0):

Change: `DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS",`

To: `DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff",`

According to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.datetime.millisecond(v=vs.110).aspx